# Drupal 8 stripping style attributes from table tags

Tags: ckeditor, drupal-8

I'm using Full HTML filter, with CKEditor.  The following filters are enabled:

- Align images
- Caption images
- Track images uploaded via a Text Editor
- Collapsible text blocks

Note that `Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML` is NOT enabled.

when I add a `style` attribute to a `table` element in Ckeditor using the Source view, specifically `"width=75%"`, it is stripped when the page is rendered.  When I edit the page again and go to Source view, the style tag is there.

What is stripping it on render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe inline styles are removed by default for security reasons. But, there has been a lot of discussion about this issue on Drupal.org over the past few years. If you're looking for a workaround and accept the risk, here are two approaches I have found:

- [How to fix: CKEditor is removing style attributes. Drupal 8.](https://medium.com/@mykola.veriga/how-to-fix-ckeditor-is-removing-style-attributes-drupal-8-ce643cf02fac)
- [Refactor Xss::attributes() to allow filtering of style attribute values](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3109650)

**Fair warning:** I have not personally implemented either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Inline style is stripped by default with Basic HTML formatter. Unless you have a specific reason why you don't want to turn on `Limit allowed HTML tags` I highly recommend that you do because it gives you a lot of control over what tags you and others can use in the wysiwyg. In addition, it allows you to add a "Styles" button with pre-configured styles so you don't have to insert inline CSS code repetitively.